# Graph non regular events by time in c#

Tags: c#, time, graph, axis

I'm trying to create graphs of incoming units of work vs the speed they are being processed.
I was going to try to use MS Chart Controls in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting but I can't find any chart that seems to suit my purpose.  The line graph is what I expected to use, but it wants regular series of data, and this will be more like int value points at irregular time intervals.

Am I overlooking some functionality of the chart controls?  Or should I look into some other data graphing package?

I expect to have a few values at random points in time, and hope to graph those with lines connecting them.  I could just sample the values say, every 15 minutes, but since the two things I want to graph are coming from different parts of my program, I can think of no way to synchronize them in series that wouldn't be prohibitively complex.  So I was hoping to just record seperate sets of values from each side, and graph them both on a time axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had not found how to do it:
The following takes values associated with irregular timestamps and graphs them just fine.  It happens to get the data from a TeaFile, but obviously they could come from anywhere.

```
        using (var ch = new Chart())
        {
            ch.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
            Series series = new Series("Connections");

            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            ch.Series.Add(series);
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
            ch.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
            ch.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
            Axis x = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.X);
            x.LineWidth = 90;
            Axis y = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.Y);
            List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
            List<double> values = new List<double>();

            using (var tf = TeaFile<IntData>.OpenRead(DataRecorder.GetFileName("Connections")))
            {
                foreach (IntData item in tf.Items)
                {
                    dates.Add(item.Time);
                    values.Add(item.Value);
                }
            }

            ch.Height = 1500;
            ch.Width = 600;
            ch.Series["Connections"].Points.DataBindXY(dates, values);
            ch.SaveImage("C:\\mypic.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```